# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: java, jdbc, aem

I am trying to get DataSource configured under OSGi configuration in AEM as follows:

```
jdbc.password="secrer"
jdbc.driver.class="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
datasource.name="ta"
jdbc.connection.uri="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ta"
jdbc.validation.query=""
datasource.svc.properties=[""]
default.readonly=B"false"
default.autocommit=B"true"
jdbc.username="aem"
pool.size=L"1000"
pool.max.wait.msec=L"999999"
```

My DataSourceProvider looks as follows

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
    import com.day.commons.datasource.poolservice.DataSourceNotFoundException;
    import com.day.commons.datasource.poolservice.DataSourcePool;

    public class DataSourceProvider extends LocalSessionFactoryBean {

        private DataSourcePool myDataSourcePool;

        public void setMyDataSourcePool(DataSourcePool myDataSourcePool) throws DataSourceNotFoundException {
            this.myDataSourcePool = myDataSourcePool;
            this.setDataSource((DataSource) this.myDataSourcePool.getDataSource("ta")); //line with issue
        }
    }
```

One "line with issue" I'm facing following issue. Is there any way I can get SQL DataSource from org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
    at com.test.datasource.DataSourceProvider.setMyDataSourcePool(DataSourceProvider.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils$MethodPropertyDescriptor.internalSet(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils$PropertyDescriptor.set(ReflectionUtils.java:378)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:939)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Spring Bean configurations

```
<reference id="dsPoolService"
        interface="com.day.commons.datasource.poolservice.DataSourcePool" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="com.australia.datasource.DataSourceProvider"> 
        <property name="myDataSourcePool" ref="dsPoolService"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: which version of dbcp do you use?

Comment: this is weird PoolingDataSource implements DataSource so you should not even need to cast it

Comment: Do you have multiple copies of the Apache DBCP JAR loaded? for example one in the application server's library directory and one in `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: This can happen if the classes are loaded by different class loaders.

Comment: how are you obtaining the instance of `DataSourcePool` that is passed to `setMyDataSourcePool` method?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto: dbcp version is 1.0.24.

Comment: I would clearly recommend to upgrade, it is more than deprecated as you cannot even download it anymore !!

Comment: @NicolasFilotto: which version I should be using. Can you please provide any reference link which I can use. FYI, dbcp bundle comes bundled with AEM product which is `Day Commons Library - JDBC pool provider for the Data Source Poolday.commons.datasource.jdbcpool` and jar name is `day.commons.datasource.jdbcpool-1.0.24.jar`

Comment: The pom of your `jdbcpool` jar would tell you the version of the `commons-dbcp` that it is dependent on. Adobe's [public repo](https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/day/commons/day.commons.datasource.jdbcpool/) has the latest version of this jar as 1.0.22 and that one depends on 1.2.2 version of `commons-dbcp`.

Answer (score -4):

By looking at the above error, it seems that you are missing the below jar file

org.apache.commons/org.apache.commons.dbcp.jar

try adding above jar

to get dataSource,try this code

conn = new GenericObjectPool(null);

```
conn.setTestOnBorrow(true);

dataSource = new PoolingDataSource(conn);
```

Comment: So how did the `org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource` object get constructed?